# Browsers can't access 127.0.0.1 but works from terminal

Tags: browser, localhost

I'm using Ubuntu 19.10 and when I try to open 127.0.0.1 in Chrome I get the

```
This site can’t be reached. 127.0.0.1 refused to connect.
```

and the same happens under Firefox

```
Unable to connect. Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at 127.0.0.1.
```

However, pinging it from the terminal works

```
> ping 127.0.0.1              
PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.044 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.067 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.053 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.066 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.056 ms
```

Similarly, netstat shows that it gets used by other programs

```
sudo netstat -antp
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8084            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1224/mono           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      951/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1061/cupsd          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:29754         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3288/vpnagentd      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9050          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1291/tor            
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:538             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1206/gdomap         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:17500           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7173/dropbox        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:17600         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7173/dropbox        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:17603         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7173/dropbox        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8200          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1789/mono-sgen      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8300          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      25574/mono-sgen
```

I'm not using proxys.

Comment: Nothing seems to accept connections on http (TCP/80) port. You should have a web server running and listening on the localhost for this.

Comment: Oh ok, but I can browse normally on the internet without problems. The only reason I care about it is that a chrome plugin (Zotero) needs to connect to 127.0.0.1

Comment: You have no webserver running, so you can't expect to see anything at that address. Why do you think that Zotero can't connect to 127.0.0.1?

Comment: @Jos: that's weird, I have a plain vanilla Ubuntu installation running. I wouldn't have thought I need to set up a webserver myself?

Comment: As far as I understand it you need two things: the Zotero tool itself, available from https://zotero.org; and the browser plugin "Zotero Connector". Perhaps you try to use the latter without installing the former?

Comment: @Jos: Thanks!!! I had completely overlooked that. It works now after installing the Zotero desktop app.

Answer (score 0):

As @Jos pointed out in a comment, the problem was using the Zotero Chrome plugin "Zotero Connector" without the Zotero desktop app. Installing the Zotero desktop app resolved the problem.